# Find max in a MongoDB collection using .Net Driver 2

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

With the 1.10 version of the .NET driver I could do something like this to get the max timestamp in the oplog collection:

```
this.oplogCollection.AsQueryable<OplogEntry>().Max(o => o.ts);
```

How can I do that with the new driver 2.0?
The documentation is basically non-existent or not helpful, so I am hoping some insiders can shed some light here.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
var result = await collection.Find(x => true).SortByDescending(d => d.ts).Limit(1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

BTW `$max` doesn't give you the biggest value as in Linq or SQL, it specifies the upper exclusive bound of a `Find`. [Documentation here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/)

Comment: Thanks, D.Rosado but that is the same solution that Janic proposed and which I had implemented already as an intermediate solution. It won't work for production as it is madness to sort the entire oplog (which can be huge) just to get the last entry. $max won't work anyways because oplog has no indexes and $max only works on indexed fields. The original solution for 1.10 had a Linq Max.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Not sure if there is a better way, but this works. I haven't found a way to implement the $max operator easily.

```
var list = await collection.Aggregate().SortByDescending((a) => a["field"]).FirstAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, except there is no Max defined on a IMongoCollection interface. Where specifically did you find examples?

Comment: My bad I assumed it was an IQueryable. I updated my answer with a solution I found. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Janic. That's the quick and hopefully temporary solution I am using already. It's quite slow, tho. Slower than the original Max query. To sort an unindexed collection like the oplog is an expensive operation, especially since the oplog grows very quickly.

Comment: D.Rosado's answer seems like the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

Since MongoDB.Driver 2.0 the best approach is to use `FindOptions` instance with specified `Limit` and `Sort` fields:

```
var options = new FindOptions<OplogEntry, OplogEntry>
{
    Limit = 1,
    Sort = Builders<OplogEntry>.Sort.Descending(o => o.ts)
};

var max = (await oplogCollection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<OplogEntry>.Empty, options)).FirstOrDefault();
```

`Sort` and `Limit` params are processed on server side. Therefore such operation is very efficient with only one result item passed to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quickest way to access the last entry in the oplog I have found so far:

```
this.oplogCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(new BsonDocument("$natural", -1)).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

It sorts the oplog in reverse natural order and since the natural order in the oplog is by ascending timestamp, grabbing the last element gives me the max.

This method is very fast and from first experiments it does not seem dependent on the oplog size, since no actual sorting takes place.

The other solutions will decrease in performance with the size of the oplog.